# How to call the testimonial component into a custom module in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am using one page website, i want shown all requirements in a one page.. Now all requirements are done except the Testimonial component part. I am using RSMonials Testimonial component. This component i want to show in the frond page, i used the its support Scroller module, static modules. But its not depends on client requirement.So i want to call the testimonial component into a custom module.. I am already searched i did not get it proper code.. So could you please help me.. Really appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Joomla extensions that allow you to publish a component as a module so you could display the RSMonials Component in a module position and include it in your one page website. For example:

Components Anywhere (free): http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/25776

Component Loader Module (paid): http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/21157

Modulix Component to Module (paid): http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/18121

In the case of Components Anywhere you'll need to add appropriate plug-in syntax into a Custom HTML module or similar.

Comment: Thanks for a response..
I am already check with those extensions. Those are commercial, but i am not ready with commercial.. And other ideas.?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a free option now that Peter van Westen has released Components Anywhere.